# How to configure nginx to make SSL work with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, raspberry-pi, reverse-proxy

I use nginx as a reverse proxy to a Rails application on my Raspberry Pi. I managed to make it work in http but I want to have https enabled.

Problem is, the Rails application doesn't seem to manage to handle https requests. This is an output of the Rails server when I try to reach a page:

```
ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x01\x01\x1C\x01\x00\x01\x18\x03\x03ɳ▒▒▒ ▒▒ڬ▒▒9C▒▒▒=▒▒▒-v_\f▒&▒%9}\x00\x00▒▒0▒,▒(▒$▒\x14▒'.
```

I'm quite new to all that but from my understanding, I should somehow communicate my certificate and key to Rails so it is able to decrypt the request?

This is the application I want to install: https://github.com/jcs/lobsters

Here is my current nginx config:

```
upstream lobsters {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    keepalive 8;
}

## Redirects all HTTP traffic to the HTTPS host
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  server_name lobsters.my.domain;

  server_tokens off;

  return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/lobsters_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/lobsters_error.log;
}

## HTTPS host
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl;
    server_name lobsters.my.domain;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/lobsters_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/lobsters_error.log;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/lobsters.my.domain/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/lobsters.my.domain/privkey.pem;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:3000;
      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
 }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You terminate the SSL connection at `nginx` then establish a new SSL connection to your backend process running on port 3000. You should probably communicate between `nginx` and port 3000 using HTTP.

Change your `proxy_pass` statement to either:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
```

or (to use your `upstream` directive):

```
proxy_pass http://lobsters;
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize nginx managed the SSL part alone and I could switch to http after that. It's much more clear now.